# call a method from a class having more than one parameter php

Tags: php

I have something like:

```
public function callClassMethod($class, $method, $params = null)
{
    $params = $params ? implode(', ', $params) : null;
    $result = (new $class())->{$method}(...);
    $this->setContent($result);
}//$params is an array
```

Is there any way that I can replace the dots so I'll be able to make a proper call? If I'm having, let's say, 1 and 100 in the array, after the implode I'll have ('1, 100'), but I need ('1', '100') so it would work. Is it possible to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [leaving the dots there...](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat)

```
public function callClassMethod($class, $method, array $params = [])
{
    $result = (new $class())->{$method}(...$params);
    $this->setContent($result);
}
```

Argument unpacking should convert that array to an argument list.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I put the dots there just so it will represent something that has to be filled :D I had no idea about this concept. Also, I removed the implode function.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was a funny coincidence that your placeholder was actually part of the solution :) Sorry, I forgot to show that you should leave `$params` an array in my initial revision.